# Using the four-parameter constructor for my school project

Tags: java

So I am doing this project for school and I am not sure on how to implement test class to put it all together. I got most of it done but don't know how to use place B in relation with Place A for geolocation.

Below is the task for the project.

> Your task is to create a program that can calculate the distances to/from geographic locations using some convenient abstractions (classes) and a bit of math.

I will post all my code for the whole project. The comments ARE directions for each part. I just need help with the last class and the directions for this part are
**        c. Using the four-parameter constructor, make a Place object that represents your school.  Use the toString method to ensure it worked.
**

In the code I have left my space below it to show where it would go. **It's in my main class**

Here is my code for each class

***GeoLocation.Java***

```
package com.GeoLocation;
//Create a class called GeoLocation that has the following:
//        a. Instance variables:
//            ▪ double latitude  – the location's latitude, as a floating-point value (double)
//            ▪ double longitude – the location's longitude, as a floating-point value
public class GeoLocation {
    double Latitude;
    double Longitude;
//public GeoLocation(double lati, double longi) – constructor, initializes instance variables to the given values
    public GeoLocation(double Lati, double Longi){
        Latitude = Lati;
        Longitude = Longi;
    }

    public GeoLocation() {

    }
//public double distanceTo(GeoLocation other) – returns the distance (in miles) from "this" GeoLocation (the location calling the method) to another GeoLocation (the other parameter variable).  The math has been done for you.  Nice!  Copy/paste the following code into this method:
    public double distanceTo(GeoLocation other) {
        double lat1  = Math.toRadians(Latitude);       //this  object's lat
        double long1 = Math.toRadians(Longitude);
        double lat2  = Math.toRadians(other.Latitude); //other object's lat
        double long2 = Math.toRadians(other.Longitude);

        //apply the spherical law of cosines
        double theCos = Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + Math.cos(lat1) *                                                   Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(long1 - long2);

        double arcLength = Math.acos(theCos);

        return arcLength * 3963.1676; //3963.1676 is ~ radius of Earth, in miles
    }
//public String toString() – returns a String representation of the GeoLocation object in the following format:  latitude: <latitude>, longitude: <longitude>
    public String toString()
    {
        String format = "Latitude = " + Latitude + " " + "," + "Longitude" + Longitude;
        return format;
    }
}
```

***Place.java***

```
package com.GeoLocation;

public class Place {

//    2. Make a new class called Place.  Place is an abstraction of a particular place, for example a business or a school.  A Place has a GeoLocation along with some more information about that place.  We say that the Place class is a client of the GeoLocation class (it uses its objects).
//        a. Instance variables
//            ▪ String      name     – a place's name, e.g. "McDonald's"
//            ▪ String      address  – the full address (street, city, etc.) of a particular place
//            ▪ GeoLocation location – the place's geographic location details
    String Name;
    String Address;
    double Latitude, Longitude;

    GeoLocation location = new GeoLocation();
//            ▪ public Place(String n, String a, double lati, double longi) – constructor, initializes all instance variables to the given values
//    • This constructor passes in the values for YOU to initialize the location object. Use these values to instantiate the object.
    public Place(String n, String a, double Lati, double Longi)
    {
        Name = n;
        Address = a;
        Latitude = Lati;
        Longitude = Longi;
        location.Latitude= Lati;
        location.Longitude = Longi;
    }
//            ▪ public double distanceTo(Place other) – returns the distance between two places.  There should only be one line inside this method:
//return location.distanceTo(other.location);
    public double distanceTo(Place other){
        return location.distanceTo(other.location);
    }
//            ▪ public Place(String n, String a, GeoLocation loc) – alternate constructor, initializes all instance variables to the given values
//                • This constructor requires an already constructed GeoLocation object.  Just like with primitive types, the constructor will use the supplied values to initialize this object's instance variables.
    public Place(String n, String a, GeoLocation loc)
    {
        Name = n;
        Address = a;
        location = loc;

    }
}
```

***Main.java*** The part I need help with is in here

```
package com.GeoLocation;
import com.GeoLocation.GeoLocation;
import com.GeoLocation.Place;

public class Main {
//Create a GeoLocation object that stores the geographic location of the Frisco ISD administration building.  Print a call to GeoLocation's toString method to ensure it worked.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GeoLocation Location = new GeoLocation();
        Location.Latitude = 33.123961;
        Location.Longitude = -96.798735;
//Using the three-parameter constructor, make a Place object that represents the Frisco ISD administration building.  Print a call to Place's toString method to ensure it worked.
        String addressA = Location.toString();
        System.out.println(addressA);
        Place PlaceA = new Place("FISD", "Address", Location);
        String AddressB = PlaceA.toString();
        System.out.println(AddressB);
//Using the four-parameter constructor, make a Place object that represents your school.  Use the toString method to ensure it worked.



//        d. Use Place's distanceTo method to output the distance between them.
//
//            ▪ Check with a neighbor to make sure you got the same distance.
//            ▪ Accuse your neighbor of faulty code if their result does not match your result.
//            ▪ Consult Google Maps to determine who was right (note that driving directions will be distance along roads, not straight-line distances; Google Maps can do both).
//                • Rejoice / weep (as applicable).
        double GeoLocDistance;
        GeoLocDistance = PlaceA.distanceTo(PlaceB);
        System.out.println(GeoLocDistance);

    }
}
```

Comment: You've done the three-parameter constructor task, haven't you? So hopefully the four-parameter constructor part should be fine: you just need to give the constructor the lat and long values rather than giving it a pre-assembled Geolocation object. I guess when it says 'toString' it means on the Geolocation object that the four-parameter constructor assembles for you since you have no toString on Place. (Unless, that is, you're expected to write one?)

Comment: @Rup my teacher gave it to us and I am so confused. I  need help

Comment: do you mean `Place mySchool = new Place("My School Name", "123 Station St", 40.7128, -74.0060)` ?

Comment: As Rup said, you've used a three-parameter constructor here: ```Place PlaceA = new Place("FISD", "Address", Location);``` . That is, you pass three different arguments to create a new ```Place```. Section c is just asking you to use the four-parameter constructor (as in Bohemian 's example). So pass in a name, address, latitude, and longitude.